# Can php URLs have numeric parameters?

Tags: php, http, url

Is this valid?:

```
http://www.SomeURL.com/Index.php?123=xyz
```

Will I be able to access the value 'xyz' under the key '123' the same ways as usual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

```
$_GET['123']
```

Comment: what's the difference between numeric index 123 and string one '123'? And what is "numerically indexed array"?

Comment: Thank you very much for the HELPFUL information, and +1 for not boosting your ego at my expense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's completely possible. It's also very easy to try by yourself.

Comment: I'm glad that you're all so very experienced, but not everything that seems easy to you, is by definition easy for everyone else.  Thanks for making me feel weak and small though.  There are no stupid questions, just stupid people, right?  So okay, I'll bite... HOW would I go about trying it by myself?  Explain to me, please, exactly how easy it is...

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to be condescending. I just assumed you had some php code you wanted to change, in which case it would be a quick test away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is something you can do.